# Grouping based on value existing in join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table Claim and Resubmission. **Claim** table has one **Resubmission** (i.e.,)**Resubmission** table belongs to **Claim** table.

Below is my table structure:

```
Claim:

ClaimPKID |   Net  |  Gross  |     Date
1         |  2000  |  6000   |  2018-01-02
2         |  1000  |  1500   |  2018-02-13
3         |  1500  |  2100   |  2018-02-25
4         |  5000  |  6700   |  2018-02-22
-----------------------------

Resubmission:

ResubmissionPKID |  ClaimID     |       Comment
1                |      2       |         abc
2                |      3       |         abc
3                |      2       |         abc
4                |      3       |         abc
```

What i want is I want to display Total of the **Gross** and **Net** amount 
with the detail of **First submission** or **Resubmission**.

If Claim Table ClaimPKID is stored in Resubmission (Which means if the claim has resubmisson) then i want to group those values seperately.

For example

Result:

```
 Net                 |  Gross              |     Claim Type
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  7000 (2000+5000)   |  12700 (6000+6700)  |  First Submission
  2500 (1000+1500)   |  3600 (1500+2100)   |    Resubmission
```

So i want to group values based on **ClaimPKID** from **Claim** Table exist in **Resubmission** Table.

I have tried below code but its not working its showing all the columns total value in a single row:

```
SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.Gross), 0), 2) as gross,
       ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.Net), 0), 2) as net,
       MAX(c.ClaimPKID)
FROM `Claim` as c
    LEFT JOIN Resubmission r on r.ClaimID = c.ClaimPKID
WHERE c.Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-28'
group by r.ClaimID
```

Kindly help me..

Comment: Im using `mysql` @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use `UNION ALL` combine two species

```
SELECT SUM(Net) AS Net,SUM(Gross) AS Gross,'Resubmission' AS 'Claim Type'
FROM Claim T 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ClaimID 
  FROM Resubmission
  GROUP BY ClaimID
)  T2  ON T.ClaimPKID = T2.ClaimID
WHERE T.Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-28'
UNION ALL 
SELECT SUM(Net) AS Net,SUM(Gross) AS Gross,'First Submission' AS 'Claim Type'
FROM Claim T 
WHERE ClaimPKID NOT IN  
(
  SELECT ClaimID 
  FROM Resubmission
  GROUP BY ClaimID
) AND T.Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-28'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa861b/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ClaimPKID  int,   Net int,  Gross  int, [Date] datetime)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1    ,2000 ,6000, '2018-01-02')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2    ,1000 ,1500, '2018-02-13')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(3    ,1500 ,2100, '2018-02-25')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(4    ,5000 ,6700, '2018-02-22')

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(ResubmissionPKID  int,   ClaimID int,  Comment varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(1 ,2  ,'abc')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(2 ,3  ,'abc')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(3 ,2  ,'abc')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(4 ,3  ,'abc')

select SUM(NET), SUM(GROSS),(CASE WHEN (ClaimID IS NULL )THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END) from @t A
left join  @t2 B ON A.ClaimPKID = B.ClaimID
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN (ClaimID IS NULL )THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Im geting this error  `An expression was expected. (near "CASE" at position 250)`

Comment: Might be you are getting error due to parentheses are missing, please check now